# Flutter, bottomSheet seems to be in loop

Tags: flutter

I have a screen that at bottom should load a banner. But when I run, the log goes crazy printing `Banner mount` and the banner never shows up.
But if I remove it (`BannerComponent`) from `bottomSheet` the banner works without the crazy print in loop.

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new StoreProvider<BookmarkState>(
      store: store,
      child: new MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        initialRoute: '/',
        routes: {
          '/': (context) => HomeScreen(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const int PAGE_SIZE = 5;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // return BannerComponent() // this whill work

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBarComponent(),
      drawer: DrawerComponent(),
      // body: this.mountBody(context),
      bottomSheet: BannerComponent(),
    );
  }
}

class BannerComponent extends StatelessWidget {
  BannerComponent();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            this.mountDFPBanner(context),
          ],
        ));
  }

  mountDFPBanner(context) {
    print('Banner mount');
    return DFPBanner(...);
  }
}
```

So, what could I be doing wrong here?

https://github.com/ko2ic/flutter_google_ad_manager/issues/33

Answer (score 0):

@Pablo, I am not sure how you're calling your HomeScreen but that could be the issue here. I did a quick test calling it within MaterialApp and seems to be working fine,

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const int PAGE_SIZE = 5;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // return BannerComponent() // this whill work

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Test')),
      //drawer: DrawerComponent(),
      // body: this.mountBody(context),
      bottomSheet: BannerComponent(),
    );
  }
}

class BannerComponent extends StatelessWidget {
  BannerComponent();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            this.mountDFPBanner(context),
          ],
        )
    );
  }

  mountDFPBanner(context) {
    print('Banner mount');
    return Container(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),height: 40.0, alignment: Alignment.center, child: Text('Banner Test', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0),));
  }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Hope this helps.